# Continuous Vaccum Level in a Metal-Semiconductor Junction

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, metals

Why is it in a metal-semiconductor junction that the vacuum levels must be continuous from metal to semiconductor? I understand why the semiconductor energy band must bend but I am having trouble understanding why it bends such that vacuum levels must align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vacuum level corresponds to a potential energy corresponding to the work done in removing an electron to the vacuum. This is a static potential and thus has to be continuous. Otherwise energy conservation would be violated.