# Why is vacuum level continuous arcoss the system?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, semiconductor-physics, vacuum, fermions

The answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282176/continuous-vaccum-level-in-a-metal-semiconductor-junction) says

> This is a static potential and thus has to be continuous. Otherwise energy conservation would be violated.

I don't find it satisfying.

How to define a "static potential"? I'm not familiar with such terminology.
Why is vaccum level a static potential and why is a static potential always continuous?

In such quantum statistical systems many approximations have to be made and, from experience, "always" is rarely the case. So does this vacuum level continuity even *always* take place?

**Long story short, I need the exact rigorous explaination of vacuum level continuity with all the possible details and nuances accounted for.**

Comment: The question [Bending of vacuum level in semiconductor junctions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/739898/bending-of-vacuum-level-in-semiconductor-junctions) is very closely related and may even be effectively a duplicate.

Comment: It is related, of course, but it does not answer my question